# Angular $watchGroup and $watch undefined in Jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Whoever said that testing Angular apps is a breeze had to be joking. Since I started writing tests for our Angular application, I consider it a great success when I move from one error message to another when running karma. Most of the examples online seem to be simplified and are not really transferable to my error cases. Now, onto the current problem I have:

I have angular-mocks.js and other angular dependencies hooked up in karma.conf.js file, I have tested config block of our app (controllers and templates matching routes) and the tests are green. Now I am trying to test controller which has $watchGroup - for some bloody reason $watchGroup is undefined (and also $watch when I tried to use it) in my jasmine test. When I comment the $watchGroup out my dummy test `expect(true).toBe(true)` is green, but with $watchGroup code in the controller (which is working fine btw) karma console reports that $watchGroup is undefined.

This is the code in the controller:

```
$scope.$watchGroup([
  'Message.AgeRangeMin',
  'Message.AgeRangeMax',
  'Message.SubscriberListFileId',
  'Message.SmsSettings.SelectedSender',
  'Message.EmailSettings.SelectedTemplate',
  'Message.PushSettings.SelectedSenders.length',
  'Message.SocialSettings.SelectedSocialNetworks.length'
  ], $scope.triggerUserForecast
);

$scope.triggerUserForecast = function () {
  commsMgmtHttpService.GetTotalReach($scope.Message)
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.UserDeliveryForecast = data;
    }, function () {
      $scope.UserDeliveryForecast.TotalUserReach = 0;
    });
};
```

This is my test case:

```
describe('forge.communications.CommsApp', function () {

  beforeEach(module('forge.communications.CommsApp'));

  describe('CreateScheduledMessageController', function () {

    var ctrl, $scope, $rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function () {

        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

            $controller = _$controller_('CreateScheduledMessageController', {
                $scope: $scope,

                $scope: {
                    ModelState: new ModelState($scope)
                },

                $location: $location,
                $modal: $modal,
                $upload: $upload
            });
        })
    });

    it("dummy should be true", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

This is the Karma console error I am getting:

Chrome 40.0.2214 (Windows 7) forge.communications.CommsApp CreateScheduledMessageController dummy should be defined FAILED TypeError: undefined is not a function at new  (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/dist/CommsApp.js:2581:12) at invoke (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular.js:4118:17) at Object.instantiate (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular.js:4129:23) at C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular.js:8320:28 at Object. (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/FrontEndTests/CommsAppTests/unit/Controllers/CreateScheduledMessage/CreateScheduledMessageController.spec.js:31:31) at Object.invoke (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular.js:4118:17) at Object.workFn (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:2257:20) at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:2229:37) at Object. (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/FrontEndTests/CommsAppTests/unit/Controllers/CreateScheduledMessage/CreateScheduledMessageController.spec.js:22:13) Error: Declaration Location at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:2228:25)at Object. (C:/work/theforge/src/TheForge/FrontEndTests/CommsAppTests/unit/Controllers/CreateScheduledMessage/CreateScheduledMessageController.spec.js:22:13) Chrome 40.0.2214 (Windows 7): Executed 15 of 15 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.12 secs) WARN [web-server]: 404: /forge/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionDaChrome 40.0.2214 (Windows 7): Executed 15 of 15 (1 FAILED) (0.415 secs / 0.12 secs)

Any advice will be of much help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I see $scope two times in you controller creation? Is it a typo?

Comment: Nope, $scope: $scope inside controller means that the left $scope - which is a property on controller gets assigned and injected $scope defined few lines above ($scope = $rootScope.$new()). You are basically passing $scope created from injected $rootScope down to controller.

Comment: I am taking about these two declaration one after another, ` $scope: ...,

                $scope: {
                    ModelState: new ModelState($scope)
                },`

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have put this statement in because of the other error I was getting, but since then I simplified my code and was stuck on $watchGroup undefined problem, completely overlooking the fact that I effectively overwrote the $scope object in $coontroller in my Jasmine tests. Removing $scope: {ModelState: new ModelState($scope)} fixed the problem.

Comment: Voting to close, as this is off-topic, essentially asking for debugging help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was overwriting the $controller's $scope property in jasmine test. Removing the following lines of code, following @Chandermani's advice fixed my problem.

```
$scope: {
  ModelState: new ModelState($scope)
}
```